# circular dependency In EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The project is a modular form. Each of the modules are located in a separate Laibary. But sometimes it is necessary to communicate between modules. Example, to create a relationship in EF.
But when I do it well, then add reference to project A to B is typically not a problem.
But when I want to add a project reference to B to A, I encounter the following error.

**a refrence to could not be added . adding this prpject as a refrence would cause a circular dependency**

Each module is a project of the h code., And each module is located in a project.
Each module has its own Domain field., And its attributes are defined.
(ORM) using the EF.
Sometimes they come in contact with the module.
For example, a module as news Comments that wish to communicate with each other. A few have a relationship.

But to insert a reference to this relationship Letting my other projects. I encounter this error
News  modula

```
public class News
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IList<Comment> Comments { set; get; }
}
```

Comment  modula

```
public class Comment
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TextComment { get; set; }

    public News  New { set; get; }
}
```

I appreciate if you can help me better design project

Answer (score 2):

I see two options here:

1. Move shared code to third library, so that A and B will reference it, but not each other
2. Merge A and B into one library

Comment: Besides these two, there is another Roche؟

Answer (score 0):

You're linking both entities together as it is recommended in pretty much every Entity Framework tutorial I have seen. However, I would only do it this way in small projects where you can put all the domain model in one assembly.

If you are working on a bigger project, where you need to separate the domain model in different assemblies according to the subdomains, I wouldn't link both entities together. Instead I would ask myself, is the news responsible for the data of its comments, or are the comments responsible for the data of the news?

This way you can find the root entity, wich could be either of them depending on the context. For example, if you decide that the news is the root, then the news would contain comments, but the comments should only reference the news Id, as they are not responsible for the news data.